# Como colocar um valor de um array em um input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Estou com dificuldade em inserir os valores de um array em um input com JS.

O que estou querendo é, fazer parecer que existe uma pessoa escrevendo e que não seja um valor que foi inserido rapidamente e completo.

(function() {

```
let campo = document.querySelector(".form-control");
let posicaoatual = 0;

setInterval(
    () => {
      posicaoatual = posicaoatual + 1;
      if  ( arraynomes[ posicaoatual ] != null ) 
      {

          campo.value = arraynomes[ posicaoatual ];
          console.log(campo.value);

      } 
      else 
      {

          console.log( 'Acabou o array, estou atoa desde:' + new Date());

      } 

    }, 5000 );
```

Este é o array.

const arraynomes = ['alexandre', 
                    'debora', 
                    'erico', 
                    'guilherme', 
                    'jessica', 
                    'ligia', 
                    'marina', 
                    'pedro', 
                    'renata'];

Lembrando que o valor do input não pode ser somente um valor inserido e sim simular uma pessoa digitando.

Qualquer dúvida no código só perguntar. Obrigado!

Comment: Pedro, inclua o seu código como texto, não como imagem, pois se alguém for testar o seu código irá ter o trabalho desnecessário de digitar tudo que está na imagem.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só para esse caso em especial, eu sugeriria utilizar um "hack" com funções assíncronas para tornar o código mais legível.

Como JavaScript possui um único `thread`, e não tem como pausar esse thread temporariamente (é até indesejável), você poderia utilizar uma `promise` que demora um certo tempo para resolver, para forçar o seu código a só continuar rodando após a resolução da `promise`.

Com uma função como a seguinte, você pode simular uma pausa dentro de uma função assíncrona:

```
function sleep(time) 
{
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time));
}
```

Dessa forma, utilizando a função `sleep`, você poderia ter uma lógica sequencial, como a seguinte:

```
async function digitarNomes(nomes) 
{
    // Para cada nome do array
    for (var nome of nomes) 
    {
        // Para cada letra do nome
        for (var letra of nome)
        {
            // Digite a letra
            textarea.value += letra;
            // E espere 0.05 segundos
            await sleep(50);
        }
        // Adicione um espaço após cada nome
        textarea.value += ' ';
        // E espere 0.15 segundos
        await sleep(150);
    }
}
```

Código funcionando:

```js
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];

function sleep(time) 
{
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, time));
}

async function digitarNomes(nomes) 
{
    for (var nome of nomes) 
    {
        for (var letra of nome) 
        {
            textarea.value += letra;
            await sleep(50);
        }
        textarea.value += ' ';
        await sleep(150);
    }
}

digitarNomes([
    'alexandre', 
    'debora', 
    'erico', 
    'guilherme', 
    'jessica', 
    'ligia', 
    'marina', 
    'pedro', 
    'renata'
]);
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!